# Como inativar a area vazia de uma div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, xhtml

Tenho uma div on adiciono eventos de mouse mas queria que o 'hit' do mouse só funcionasse onde existisse conteúdo e ignorasse os 'margins' po ex.

Segue a imagem( a area de amarelo é a area que quero 'inativar' já que não há conteudo ) que ilustra o problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Por uma limitação do projeto não possa adicionar os eventos do mouse no conteúdo.

Attm

Comment: O `margin` já é ignorado para eventos nos elementos, no seu caso o problema seria no `padding`, não?

Comment: Então denho a div e uma imagem com o margin:0 auto só que o hit do evento continua pegando na area en branco(sem conteudo) TT

Comment: E se você usar a própria imagem para acionar o evento ao passar o mouse?

Comment: Ou ainda, usar o mouseover de todos os filhos do teu div principal, e não o próprio div, desta forma fica mais dinâmico ainda.

Comment: Então luigibertaco o problema é que por ex: eu tenho a div que aparece no mouseover no momento que aparecer a div e o mouse estiver em cima a função vai ser chamada um segunda fez de forma desnecessaria... mas tranquilo alguns ifs devem resolver valel

Comment: Posta o código.

Comment: Sem examinar o código fica difícil sugerir uma solução.
Dê uma olhada nessa matéria: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Muito obrigado Maujor, muito esclarecedor o link, mas resolvi o meu problema eliminando o espaço em branco da div não foi a solução que queria mas agora o problema se foi, valeu

Comment: @DouglasdosSantos coloca então essa sua solução como resposta para que outros usuários possam ver mais claramente e esta pergunta saia do rol de perguntas sem resposta.

Comment: @DouglasdosSantos você poderia criar duas divs, uma que conteria o espaço em branco que vc precisa, e outra onde ficaria o conteúdo com o hit.

Answer (score 1):

Podes atingir o teu objetivo detetanto onde é que o clique ocorreu em relação ao teu elemento:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/mow9xpad/)

```
$("#meuElemento").click(function(e){
    var meuOffset = $(this).offset(),
        relX      = e.pageX - meuOffset.left,
        relY      = e.pageY - meuOffset.top,
        largura   = $(this).width(),
        limite    = 15;

    // Onde foi o clique?
    if (relX>limite && relX<(largura-limite))
        $('p span').html("Dentro");
    else
        $('p span').html("Fora");
});
```

**A Explicar:**

A variável `relX` vai conter a distância em pixeis deste a esquerda do teu elemento até ao local onde o utilizador clicou.

A variável `limite` define o limite do clique, ou seja, indica que até esse valor tanto à contar da direita como a contar da esquerda o clique é considerado "fora".

No exemplo pode ser visto que o clique na zona a branco que corresponde a uma margem de 15 pixeis igual à tua imagem, dá "fora". O clique sobre a cor verde dá "dentro".

[image: Ilustração do exemplo no JSFiddle]

Foi utilizado o método de jQuery [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) para traduzir as coordenadas [`event.pageX`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) e [`event.pageY`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) originados com o clique do rato para uma posição em pixeis relativa ao elemento.